# RewriteRule : getting one parameter without QSA

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this url:

```
example.com/dolce-vita/fr/camping.php?CAMPING-LES-MYRTILLES&p=839000231
```

And i want it to be redirected to this one:

```
example.com/rechercher-sur-le-site-45-1.html?q=CAMPING-LES-MYRTILLES
```

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule camping\.php?(.*) /rechercher-sur-le-site-45-1.html?q=$1 [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteRule camping\.php\?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)& /rechercher-sur-le-site-45-1.html?q=$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

I'm a bit lost as i **can't use** *QSA* flag : in the url i want to rewrite, i have `p=XX` wich is a parameter i already use (ex : `/rechercher-sur-le-site-45-1.html?q=` means `index.php?p=45`) so if i use QSA, it adds `p=839000231` at the end and overwrites my `p=45` parameter...

Tanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Where is your htaccess ? In which folder ?

Comment: On root, he's interpreted i have many other rules on it. This is the one i can't make working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^dolce-vita/fr/camping\.php$ /rechercher-sur-le-site-45-1.html?q=%1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

More info about `%{QUERY_STRING}` [here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString)
More info about `mod_rewrite` [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Works ! huge... no i need to know how you made it :D

Comment: You have to use `QUERY_STRING` when parsing *query string parameters*. You can find more info here for example: [link](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString)

Comment: Never used it but it could have saved many time to me before...
Thanks a lot

Comment: Yep. You're welcome, you can see all possibilities of `mod_rewrite` here: [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Don't forget to accept my answer if it was useful